# page and table forming in latex

Tags: tables

In the following code I am trying to fit the table all on one page but the last 2 columns do not fit on the page. I am looking for some help with fixing this, thanks! I have included a screenshot

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l>{$}c<{$}llc} \toprule
& \text{Symbol}
        & \hfil Description                   & Units     & Estimated Value\\
\midrule
Parameters
& \mu_{H-YF}     & Human per capita mortality rate from YF                  & \si{1/days}  & \\
& \mu_H     & Human per capita mortality rate        & \si{1/days}  &  \\
& \mu_{H-AVD}     & Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AVD      & \si{1/days} &  \\
& \mu_{H-AND}     & Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AND & \si{1/days} &  \\
& \mu_{M}     & Mosquito per capita mortality rate & \si{1/days} &  \\
& \alpha_{M}     & Mosquito per capita birth rate & \si{1/days} &  \\
& \beta     & Mosquito per capita transmission rate (exposed to infectious) & \si{1/days} &  \\
& r     & Human per capita recovery rate (infectious to recovered) & \si{1/days} &  \\
& b    & Mosquito per capita biting rate on humans & \si{1/days} & \\
& p_H    & Probability that an infective bite generates new infection in humans  & \si{1/days} & \\
& p_M   & Probability that a new infection in the mosquito is generated  & \si{1/days} & \\
& \sigma    & Human per capita recovered to susceptible transition rate & \si{1/days} & \\
& e    & Vaccine efficiency & unitless & \\
& \gamma    & Human per capita rate of vaccination & \si{1/days} & \\
& w    & Human per capita rate of waning immunity & \si{1/days} & \\
\midrule
Initial Conditions
& V(0)  & initial volume of water above the hole    & \si{mL}   & 776.15 \\ \midrule
Variables
& S_H & Number of susceptible humans & number   & $S_H \geq 0 $ \\
& I_H & Number of infected humans & number   & $I_H \geq 0 $ \\
& R_H & Number of recovered humans & number   & $R_H \geq 0 $ \\
& N_H & Number of total human population & number   & $N_H \geq 0 $ \\
& S_M & Number of susceptible mosquitoes & number   & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
& E_M & Number of exposed mosquitoes & number   & $E_M \geq 0 $ \\
& I_M & Number of infected mosquitoes & number   & $I_M \geq 0 $ \\
& N_M & Number of total mosquito population & number   & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first column of your table is mostly empty except for the three items "Parameters", "Initial Conditions", and "Variables". Making these items into headers lets you economize on a whole column, saving much space. I would also suggest that you (a) employ a `tabularx` environment and allow linebreaks in the third (formerly: fourth) column and (b) make the final column less wide by introducing a line break between the two words in the header cell.

[image]

---

*Addendum*. For good measure, here's an additional solution. It's similar to the one above in that it (a) employs a `tabularx` environment and (b) rearranges the material in order to get rid of the entire first column. The main change is more visual grouping of the tabular material, by inserting a bit of whitespace after every fourth row. In addition, the contents of the final two columns are not center-set rather than left-aligned.

[image]

```
%% Code for first solution
%% -----------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,amsmath,
            geometry,tabularx,ragged2e}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Estimated}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LYlp{\mylen} @{}} 
\toprule
\text{Symbol} & Description & Units & Estimated Value\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Parameters} \\ 
\mu_{H\text{-YF}}  & Human per capita mortality rate from YF       & \si{1/days} \\
\mu_H              & Human per capita mortality rate               & \si{1/days} \\
\mu_{H\text{-AVD}} & Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AVD  & \si{1/days} \\
\mu_{H\text{-AND}} & Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AND  & \si{1/days} \\
\mu_{M}            & Mosquito per capita mortality rate            & \si{1/days} \\
\alpha_{M}         & Mosquito per capita birth rate                & \si{1/days} \\
\beta              & Mosquito per capita transmission rate (exposed to infectious) & \si{1/days} \\
r                  & Human per capita recovery rate (infectious to recovered) & \si{1/days} \\
b                  & Mosquito per capita biting rate on humans     & \si{1/days} \\
p_H                & Probability that an infective bite generates new infection in humans & \si{1/days} \\
p_M                & Probability that a new infection in the mosquito is generated  & \si{1/days} \\
\sigma             & Human per capita recovered to susceptible transition rate & \si{1/days} \\
e                  & Vaccine efficiency                            & unitless \\
\gamma             & Human per capita rate of vaccination          & \si{1/days} \\
w                  & Human per capita rate of waning immunity      & \si{1/days} \\ 
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Initial Conditions}\\
V(0)               & initial volume of water above hole & \si{\milli\liter} & 776.15 \\ 
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Variables}\\
S_H & Number of susceptible humans     & number   & $S_H \geq 0 $ \\
I_H & Number of infected humans        & number   & $I_H \geq 0 $ \\
R_H & Number of recovered humans       & number   & $R_H \geq 0 $ \\
N_H & Number of total human population & number   & $N_H \geq 0 $ \\
S_M & Number of susceptible mosquitoes & number   & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
E_M & Number of exposed mosquitoes     & number   & $E_M \geq 0 $ \\
I_M & Number of infected mosquitoes    & number   & $I_M \geq 0 $ \\
N_M & Number of total mosquito population & number& $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}



%% Code for second solution
%% ------------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,amsmath,geometry,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LXcc @{}} 
\toprule
$Symbol$ & Description & Units & Estimated\\
& & & Value\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Parameters} \\ 
\mu_H                & Human per capita mortality rate              & \si{1/days} \\
\mu_{H\textrm{-YF}}  & Human per capita mortality rate from YF      & \si{1/days} \\
\mu_{H\textrm{-AVD}} & Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AVD & \si{1/days} \\
\mu_{H\textrm{-AND}} & Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AND & \si{1/days} \\
\addlinespace
\mu_{M}            & Mosquito per capita mortality rate             & \si{1/days} \\
\alpha_{M}         & Mosquito per capita birth rate                 & \si{1/days} \\
\beta              & Mosquito per capita transmission rate (exposed 
                     to infectious) & \si{1/days} \\
r                  & Human per capita recovery rate (infectious to 
                     recovered) & \si{1/days} \\
\addlinespace
b                  & Mosquito per capita biting rate on humans      & \si{1/days} \\
p_H                & Probability that infective bite generates new 
                     infection in humans & \si{1/days} \\
p_M                & Probability that new infection in mosquito is 
                     generated   & \si{1/days} \\
\sigma             & Human per capita recovered to susceptible 
                     transition rate & \si{1/days} \\
\addlinespace
e                  & Vaccine efficiency                             & unitless \\
\gamma             & Human per capita rate of vaccination           & \si{1/days} \\
w                  & Human per capita rate of waning immunity       & \si{1/days} \\ 

\addlinespace\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Initial Conditions}\\
V(0)               & Initial volume of water above hole & 
                     \si{\milli\liter} & 776.15 \\ 

\addlinespace\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Variables}\\
S_H & Number of susceptible humans     & number   & $S_H \geq 0 $ \\
I_H & Number of infected humans        & number   & $I_H \geq 0 $ \\
R_H & Number of recovered humans       & number   & $R_H \geq 0 $ \\
N_H & Number of total human population & number   & $N_H \geq 0 $ \\
\addlinespace
S_M & Number of susceptible mosquitoes & number   & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
E_M & Number of exposed mosquitoes     & number   & $E_M \geq 0 $ \\
I_M & Number of infected mosquitoes    & number   & $I_M \geq 0 $ \\
N_M & Number of total mosquito population & number& $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose this layout based on `tabularx` and `geometry` (to have more sensible margins, if you don't use margin notes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}%
\centering%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.5em}>{$}c<{$}Xlc} \toprule
& \text{Symbol}
        & \centering Description & Units & \makecell{Estimated\\ Value}\\
\midrule
\rlap{\em Parameters} \\[-2.5ex]
& \mu_{H-YF} & Human per capita mortality rate from YF & \si{1/days} & \\
& \mu_H & Human per capita mortality rate & \si{1/days} & \\
& \mu_{H-AVD} & Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AVD & \si{1/days} & \\
& \mu_{H-AND} & Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AND & \si{1/days} & \\
& \mu_{M} & Mosquito per capita mortality rate & \si{1/days} & \\
& \alpha_{M} & Mosquito per capita birth rate & \si{1/days} & \\
& \beta & Mosquito per capita transmission rate (exposed to infectious) & \si{1/days} & \\
& r & Human per capita recovery rate (infectious to recovered) & \si{1/days} & \\
& b & Mosquito per capita biting rate on humans & \si{1/days} & \\
& p_H & Probability that an infective bite generates new infection in humans & \si{1/days} & \\
& p_M & Probability that a new infection in the mosquito is generated & \si{1/days} & \\
& \sigma & Human per capita recovered to susceptible transition rate & \si{1/days} & \\
& e & Vaccine efficiency & unitless & \\
& \gamma & Human per capita rate of vaccination & \si{1/days} & \\
& w & Human per capita rate of waning immunity & \si{1/days} & \\
\midrule
\rlap{\em Initial Conditions}\\[-2.5ex]
& V(0) & initial volume of water above the hole & \si{mL} & 776.15 \\ \midrule
\rlap{\em Variables}\\[-2.5ex]
& S_H & Number of susceptible humans & number & $S_H \geq 0 $ \\
& I_H & Number of infected humans & number & $I_H \geq 0 $ \\
& R_H & Number of recovered humans & number & $R_H \geq 0 $ \\
& N_H & Number of total human population & number & $N_H \geq 0 $ \\
& S_M & Number of susceptible mosquitoes & number & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
& E_M & Number of exposed mosquitoes & number & $E_M \geq 0 $ \\
& I_M & Number of infected mosquitoes & number & $I_M \geq 0 $ \\
& N_M & Number of total mosquito population & number & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can save space by dividing the table into three sections, instead of an almost empty first column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\sisetup{exponent-product=\cdot}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  >{$}c<{$}
  >{\raggedright}X
  c
  c
  @{}
}
\toprule
\text{Symbol} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Description} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Unit} &
  Estimated Value \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\itshape Parameters} \\
\mu_{\mathrm{YF}} &
  Human per capita mortality rate from Yellow  Fever &
  1/days & \num{3.5e-4} \\
\mu_{\mathrm{H}} &
  Human per capita mortality rate &
  1/days & \num{3.5e-5} \\
\mu_{\mathrm{AVD}} &
  Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AVD &
  1/days & \\
\mu_{\mathrm{AND}} &
  Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AND &
  1/days & \\
r &
  Human per capita recovery rate (infectious to recovered) &
  1/days & \num{0.143} \\
b &
  Mosquito average daily biting rate on humans &
  1/days & \num{3.00} \\
p_{\mathrm{H}} &
  Probability that an infective bite generates new infection in humans &
   unitless & $0 \leq p_{\mathrm{H}} \leq 1$ \\
e &
  Vaccine efficiency &
  unitless & $0 \leq e \leq 1$ \\
\gamma &
  Human per capita rate of vaccination &
  1/days & \num{0.500} \\
w &
  Human per capita rate of waning immunity induced by vaccination &
  1/days & \num{0.100} \\
\mu_{\mathrm{M}} & Mosquito per capita mortality rate &
  1/days & \num{0.09} \\
\alpha_{\mathrm{M}} &
  Mosquito per capita birth rate &
  1/days & \num{0.537} \\
\beta &
  Mosquito per capita transmission rate (exposed to infectious) &
  1/days & \num{0.143} \\
p_{\mathrm{M}} &
  Probability an infection occurs when a mosquito bites an infective host &
  unitless & $0 \leq p_{\mathrm{M}} \leq 1 $ \\

\addlinespace[1ex]

\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\itshape Initial Conditions} \\
V(0) &
  initial volume of water above the hole &
  \si{\milli\liter} & \num{776.15} \\

\addlinespace[1ex]

\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\itshape Variables} \\
S_{\mathrm{H}} &
  Number of susceptible humans &
  number & $S_{\mathrm{H}} \geq 0 $ \\
I_{\mathrm{H}} &
  Number of infected humans &
  number & $I_{\mathrm{H}} \geq 0 $ \\
R_{\mathrm{H}} &
  Number of recovered humans &
  number & $R_{\mathrm{H}} \geq 0 $ \\
N_{\mathrm{H}} &
  Number of total human population &
  number & $N_{\mathrm{H}} \geq 0 $ \\
S_{\mathrm{M}} &
  Number of susceptible mosquitoes &
  number & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
E_{\mathrm{M}} &
  Number of exposed mosquitoes &
  number & $E_{\mathrm{M}} \geq 0 $ \\
I_{\mathrm{M}} &
  Number of infected mosquitoes &
  number & $I_{\mathrm{M}} \geq 0 $ \\
N_{\mathrm{M}} &
  Number of total mosquito population &
  number & $S_{\mathrm{M}} \geq 0 $ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Some points to note:

1. Use `\num` to ensure consistent typesetting of numbers
2. `\si` should be used for SI units, which 1/days isn't
3. `\extrarowheight` adds space also in unwanted places
4. Textual subscripts should be typeset upright

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never used again a tabularx but seems to work here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit,vesti bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae,

{\footnotesize
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{1.45cm}>{$}c<{$}Xlp{1.5cm}} \toprule
& \text{Symbol}
        & \hfil Description                   & Units     & Estimated Value\\
\midrule
Parameters
& \mu_{H-YF}     & Human per capita mortality rate from YF                  & \si{1/days}  & \\
& \mu_H     & Human per capita mortality rate        & \si{1/days}  &  \\
& \mu_{H-AVD}     & Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AVD      & \si{1/days} &  \\
& \mu_{H-AND}     & Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AND & \si{1/days} &  \\
& \mu_{M}     & Mosquito per capita mortality rate & \si{1/days} &  \\
& \alpha_{M}     & Mosquito per capita birth rate & \si{1/days} &  \\
& \beta     & Mosquito per capita transmission rate (exposed to infectious) & \si{1/days} &  \\
& r     & Human per capita recovery rate (infectious to recovered) & \si{1/days} &  \\
& b    & Mosquito per capita biting rate on humans & \si{1/days} & \\
& p_H    & Probability that an infective bite generates new infection in humans  & \si{1/days} & \\
& p_M   & Probability that a new infection in the mosquito is generated  & \si{1/days} & \\
& \sigma    & Human per capita recovered to susceptible transition rate & \si{1/days} & \\
& e    & Vaccine efficiency & unitless & \\
& \gamma    & Human per capita rate of vaccination & \si{1/days} & \\
& w    & Human per capita rate of waning immunity & \si{1/days} & \\
\midrule
Initial Conditions
& V(0)  & initial volume of water above the hole    & \si{mL}   & 776.15 \\ \midrule
Variables
& S_H & Number of susceptible humans & number   & $S_H \geq 0 $ \\
& I_H & Number of infected humans & number   & $I_H \geq 0 $ \\
& R_H & Number of recovered humans & number   & $R_H \geq 0 $ \\
& N_H & Number of total human population & number   & $N_H \geq 0 $ \\
& S_M & Number of susceptible mosquitoes & number   & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
& E_M & Number of exposed mosquitoes & number   & $E_M \geq 0 $ \\
& I_M & Number of infected mosquitoes & number   & $I_M \geq 0 $ \\
& N_M & Number of total mosquito population & number   & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the font size, you might also want to allow the table to occupy some space of the left and right margin. (The red line beneath the table indicates the textwidth).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{changepage}



\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{1.15\textwidth}{l>{$}c<{$}Ylc} \toprule
& \text{Symbol}
        & \hfil Description                   & Units     & \makecell[c]{Estimated \\ Value}\\
\midrule
Parameters
& \mu_{H-YF}     & Human per capita mortality rate from YF                  & \si{1/days}  & \\
& \mu_H     & Human per capita mortality rate        & \si{1/days}  &  \\
& \mu_{H-AVD}     & Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AVD      & \si{1/days} &  \\
& \mu_{H-AND}     & Human per capita mortality rate from YEL-AND & \si{1/days} &  \\
& \mu_{M}     & Mosquito per capita mortality rate & \si{1/days} &  \\
& \alpha_{M}     & Mosquito per capita birth rate & \si{1/days} &  \\
& \beta     & Mosquito per capita transmission rate (exposed to infectious) & \si{1/days} &  \\
& r     & Human per capita recovery rate (infectious to recovered) & \si{1/days} &  \\
& b    & Mosquito per capita biting rate on humans & \si{1/days} & \\
& p_H    & Probability that an infective bite generates new infection in humans  & \si{1/days} & \\
& p_M   & Probability that a new infection in the mosquito is generated  & \si{1/days} & \\
& \sigma    & Human per capita recovered to susceptible transition rate & \si{1/days} & \\
& e    & Vaccine efficiency & unitless & \\
& \gamma    & Human per capita rate of vaccination & \si{1/days} & \\
& w    & Human per capita rate of waning immunity & \si{1/days} & \\
\midrule
\makecell[lt]{Initial \\Conditions}
& V(0)  & initial volume of water above the hole    & \si{mL}   & 776.15 \\ \midrule
Variables
& S_H & Number of susceptible humans & number   & $S_H \geq 0 $ \\
& I_H & Number of infected humans & number   & $I_H \geq 0 $ \\
& R_H & Number of recovered humans & number   & $R_H \geq 0 $ \\
& N_H & Number of total human population & number   & $N_H \geq 0 $ \\
& S_M & Number of susceptible mosquitoes & number   & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
& E_M & Number of exposed mosquitoes & number   & $E_M \geq 0 $ \\
& I_M & Number of infected mosquitoes & number   & $I_M \geq 0 $ \\
& N_M & Number of total mosquito population & number   & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changes I made in comparison to the original code:

- Used `adjustwidth` from the `changepage` package to allow the table to occupy space from the margins.
- Used `makecell` for linebreaks in cells.
- Used a flexible width column and a `tabularx`.